# List view (fragment) with swipe view with arrays

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a project in mind but do not know if it's possible realization, I need to have 3 tabs with swipe view. In the first i have a list view where it should be possible to make a long click and add, delete or edit records in an array . I see this a little complicated , just need some lights on how 'll add a list view , load the data within a fragment.

Comment: First try to execute what you *have in mind*.

Comment: but i dont know where start, and if its possible or not

Comment: Try some tutorials and answer is *yes* what you want to do is possible.

Comment: Are you still working on this and needing help?